# How to get a scene information from Unread Engine 4?

Tags: unreal-4, 3d-meshes, assets, fbx

I learn game engine development and I was interested to work not only with box and sphere meshes also with a large model with difference meshes and textures in this model. I bought a 3d model. The model has  .uasset and fbx file formats. I thought that I can build a scene from fbxs files but unfortunately in fbs files don't have a scene information( only meshes and textures ) unlike  .uasset. Can I get only a scene infomation from Unread Engine 4 to fbx file ?

Comment: What scene information are you trying to get, and for what purpose?

Comment: I think a transform matrix will be enough per instance mesh in order to construct the model

Comment: [Model](https://www.cgtrader.com/3d-models/exterior/sci-fi-exterior/sci-fi-industrial-base-unreal-project) which I bought.